# how to link the onclick function with google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code, which on clicked alert me the lat and lng of a place. How can i integrate google map to show the place in google map.

```
$("body").on("click",".names",function(){

        var latitude = $(this).children(".latitude").text();
        alert(latitude);

    });
```

Thanks

Updata .. this is the database that i had made. So when i click on one of the list it  alert me the lat n long. Instead of giving me alert of lat n lng. i want to show the place in google map. Hope this clarifies my point

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var db = openDatabase('To Do', '1.0', 'To Do', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function(tx){
 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM BNames', [], querySucess, errorCB);
});

function querySucess(tx, results){
    var len = results.rows.length;
        if(len > 0){
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){           //<span here>//
    $("#list").append("<ul><li class='names'<br>" + results.rows.item(i).id +   "   "+ results.rows.item(i).name + "<span class='latitude'> " + results.rows.item(i).latitude +  "</span><span class='latitude'> " + results.rows.item(i).longtitude +" </span> [<a href='#' onclick='deletefunction(" + results.rows.item(i).id + ");'>DELETE</a>] </li></ul>");
}

}else{
    console.log("You Have No BuildingNames");
}

}
function errorCB(err){
    alert("Error" + err.code);
}
});

HTML 

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="BName"/>
<input type="text" id="latitude"  placeholder="latitude"/>
<input type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude"/>
<input type="button" id="Add" value="Add"/>

<div id="list"> </div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well for starters you'll need to also get the longitude.  This code just seems to give you a latitude

Comment: it will show both lat and long .. children of latitude is longitude ..

Comment: it might help to show us the contents of the HTML that your click event is bound to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
    $("body").on("click",".names",function(){
    //next two lines most likely need replacing.
    var latitude = $("#latitude").text();
    var longitude = $("#longitude").text();
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude));
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
      });

});
```

Comment: yeah something like this .. when i click on the list instead of giving me alert it would show me the location of the cordinate in the google map